# In SuiteCRM in workflow module display phone related fields in dropdown

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm fresher working in SuiteCRM, please help me out with this requirement.
In workflow, in add action section I kept one dropdown list in which all fields are displayed according to module selected.
For example, if I select Account module, all fields related to accounts will be displayed in dropdown.

I want only office_phone and alernate_phone fileds to displayed in that dropdown,of selected module.

dropdown of all fields as per module selected:

[image]